# Clickable response such as a button in Dialogflow

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I have been developing a chatbot for my android app using dialogflow and its working perfectly. But now I've a requirement to get a clickable response from my chabot. For example, let's say that the app user is asking for a specific location. I want Dialogflow chatbot to return a button or a link as the response so that the user could click on that and be redirected to the google maps.

I have went through a lot of tutorials, blogs and docs yet I've not been able to find a satisfying answer. If you could help me with a code example as well, that would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Dialogflow to integrate with your own system (as opposed to something like Facebook Messenger, Actions on Google, or other bot platforms) using the Detect Intent API, then you can include any data you want in the [`payload`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works#response_format) object of your webhook response. This is passed back to you in the response to your Detect Intent call in the [response body](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#body.DetectIntentResponse.SCHEMA_REPRESENTATION) in the [`queryResult.webhookPayload`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/QueryResult) object.

You can include in here any information you wish, and render it however you'd like.

Comment: thank you so much for your help @Prisoner. Could you give me a sample code on how to do what you suggested?

Comment: It is difficult to provide you sample code since you haven't provided any to build from, so I'm not sure if you want sample code on the webhook fulfillment, in your client, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the Intent section in Dialogflow, click on "Google Assistant" in Responses.
Select "Link Out Suggestion" which is used for giving a clickable link.
In case if you just want the button without link then you can use "Suggestion Chips".
On the UI code you will need to parse it and render it as clickable button.

See screenshots below from dialogflow:
[image: Select Link Out Suggestion]
[image: Enter name and URL]

For more details, refer to https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/rich-message-button-response-dialogflow-chatbot/

Comment: ANd what if I want several buttons and associate each button to its link

Comment: click on "Add Responses" and add another

Comment: It was not possible with link out suggestion it gives you only one possible button

Comment: if you are using Kommunicate with Dialogflow, use custom payload to add multiple links https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/message-types#link-button Alternatively, create your own json payload format and then render it on the UI

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use Google **Maps URLs** for this purpose. These provide a Universal Cross-platform solution.

Follow these steps:

Based on user Responses, encode a Map URL as shown in examples here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

For example, consider the URL from the guide above

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY
```

Then use 
Buttons in Basic Card as follows

```
app.intent('demo', (conv, params) => {
    // Create a basic card with the URL 
    conv.ask(new BasicCard({
      text: `This is a basic card with Map Response.`,
      subtitle: 'This is a subtitle',
      title: 'Title: Open Map',
      buttons: new Button({
        title: 'Open Map as per URL',
        url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY',
      })
    }));
}
```

You can also use other **Responses** (such as linkOutSuggestion ) as described here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But isn't basic card responses support only to existing clients like messenger, viber and etc? I have been looking around a lot and that's what I found out. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

all.For this problem solution,google assistant is not proper as Google assistant will sunset in july 2023. So suggest apart fro Google assistan for rich response

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).