# How to design restricted flow based bots in dialogflow?

Tags: python, nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I am new to dialogflow, I was trying to build a rule based bot on it with some restricted flows.

e.g.

```
Order  |  Account|  Others   
->Order

Cash | Online
->Cash

Address |Pickup
```

I wanted to have buttons that would allow users only certain actions to be performed i.e. clicking a button and not typing anything as of now. I am using Dialogflow ES. Is there some way or feature in Dialogflow ES or CX?

Any related documentation would also be great help.

Comment: You may want to check out this related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246705/clickable-response-such-as-a-button-in-dialgflow and might help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Rich response message](http://cloud/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages) for this purpose:

1. Go to the Dialogflow ES Console.
2. Select an agent.
3. Select Intents in the left sidebar menu.
4. Select an intent.
5. Scroll down to the Responses section.

> You can define responses for platform-specific tabs, which only work on the corresponding platforms. You can also opt to use the default responses for a specific platform, so you do not need to create duplicate text responses for all platforms.

1. Select the tab for your desired platform. If the desired platform tab is not shown, click the add add button and select it.
2. Click the Add Responses button. A dropdown shows the response types supported by the platform.
3. Choose the response type. These are described below.
4. Enter fields for the selected response type.
5. Add more platform tabs and responses as needed. You can add up to 10 ordered messages in each tab.
6. Click Save.

Checkout the [Quick reply responses](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#quick) where you can add buttons as the default responses.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Thanks but I still had one doubt?


BIzza Bot -> 1 |Order|   
                      2 |Customer Support|

Order-> 1 Pizza 
               2 Beverage
               3 talk to someone
Customer Support ->1. live SMS
                                   2. callback

                PIzza ->  1Cash
                               2 online                    
Let the flow be Opens bot :
 Order->Pizza->cash
If all of these are to be buttons. I can suggest an answer for order as (Pizza, beverage and talk to someone) but how do I link Pizza button to cash |Online buttons

Comment: @If I add buttons in google assistant platform and want to use answers as buttons on my own web demo app how to that

Comment: Hi! check [Dialogflow Messenger](http://cloud/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger), there also examples on this link.